# how to do this in c: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('char [3]' and 'int')

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, char, nested-loops

wanted:

```
* * * * *
  * * * * *
    * * * * *
      * * * * *
        * * * * *
```

###### my code

```c
//THIS CODE IS NOT WORKABLE
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
  char arr[] = "* * * * *";
  printf("%s\n", arr);
  for (int i=1; i<5; i++) {
    char sp[] = "  "*i;
    printf("%s\n", sp[i]+arr);
  } 
  return 0;
}
```

###### i do this in python:

```py
aa = '* * * * *'
print(aa)
for i in range(1,5):
  print('  '*i + aa)
```

##### --> how to fix this in c? looking forward some python-like style code in c(as simple as possible)

Comment: C doesn't have any built-in way to duplicate a string like that. Just print spaces in a loop.

Comment: Look at, for example, `printf("%*s\n", 9 + 2 * i, arr);`

Answer (score 0):

There is no an equivalent binary operator * in C as in Python that allows to propagate a string.

But in any case your approach even in Python is not flexible because it deals with the fixed string `"* * * * *"`.

To output the pattern in C you should use loops as for example shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        const char c = '*';
        
        printf( "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit ): " );
        
        int n = 0;
        
        if ( scanf( "%d", &n ) != 1 || n <= 0 ) break;
        
        putchar( '\n' );
        
        for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            printf( "%*c", 2 * i + 1, c );
            for ( int j = 1; j < n; j++ ) printf( " %c", c );
            putchar( '\n' );
        }
        
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit ): 1

*

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit ): 2

* *
  * *

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit ): 3

* * *
  * * *
    * * *

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit ): 4

* * * *
  * * * *
    * * * *
      * * * *

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit ): 5

* * * * *
  * * * * *
    * * * * *
      * * * * *
        * * * * *

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit ): 0
```